# How to convert a string to date in mysql inserting from a txt parser? - JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, string, date

I'm reading data from a txt file using a parser, and record them in the database as follows:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/RPR/Desktop/test.txt"));

        String data[] = new String[6];
        String line = reader.readLine();

        while (line != null) {

            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, ";\"");

            data[0] = st.nextToken();
            data[1] = st.nextToken(); 
            data[2] = st.nextToken();
            data[3] = st.nextToken();
            data[4] = st.nextToken();
            data[5] = st.nextToken();

            stm.executeUpdate(new StringBuilder().append("replace into records (date_record, hour, IdSensor, Temp, Hum, dew_point) values ('").append(data[0]).append("','").append(data[1]).append("','").append(data[2]).append("','").append(data[3]).append("','").append(data[4]).append("','").append(data[5]).append("')").toString());

            line = reader.readLine();
```

The date is in varchar format and I wanted to turn it on type date. 
I've been searching and saw this way:

```
date_format(str_to_date(date_record, '%d-%m-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

However when I put this in my code gives error in inserting.

*Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%d-%Y')','10:32:53','BrgTH002','21.9','53.1','11.9')' at line 1*

Can anyone help me please? 
I'm a MYSQL newbie :S

I apologize if the question I'm doing is more directed to java.

I tried entering that code.`date_format(str_to_date(date_record, '%d-%m-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')`
 But it gives me error in the insert. Actually the error is now in java, Can anyone help me?

If I'm right, i need to change that function

```
stm.executeUpdate(new StringBuilder().append("replace into records (date_record, hour, IdSensor, Temp, Hum, dew_point) values ('").append(data[0]).append("','").append(data[1]).append("','").append(data[2]).append("','").append(data[3]).append("','").append(data[4]).append("','").append(data[5]).append("')").toString());
```

But I dont no how to do :S

Comment: My suggestion is print the String data[] and check, before inserting what is the format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). Aside from sparing you from [SQL Injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), it makes handling various data types a lot easier:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yy");

PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("replace into records"
   + " (date_record, hour, IdSensor, Temp, Hum, dew_point) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)");

stmt.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(dateFormat.parse(data[0]).getTime()));
stmt.setInt(2, data[1]);
// etc...

stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I try what you said. But gives me a error:
stmt.setDate(1, dateFormat.parse(data[0]); 
no suitable method found for setDate(int,java.util.Date)
    method com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setDate(int,java.sql.Date,java.util.Calendar) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setDate(int,java.sql.Date) is not applicable
      (actual argument java.util.Date cannot be converted to java.sql.Date by method invocation conversion)

Comment: @user3320956 My bad, you need a java.sql.Date, and DateFormat returns a java.util.Date. Example code updated to account for that.

Comment: Thanks for the help. 
Worked very well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead try using . If it doesn't work then there is error in your java code probably.

```
date_format(str_to_date(date_record, '%d,%m,%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d');
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.
Like  I said, I tried entering that code. But it gives me error in the insert. Actually the error is now in java, Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-literals.html)

it should be good if you do this:

`STR_TO_DATE('04/04/2012 04:03:35 AM', '%d/%m/%Y %r')`

Or use the `SimpleDateFormat` for Java to get the same pattern !